# Is there any way to move a workflow from one site to another?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

When I set up my workflow for a project I'm working on, I didn't set it up as a reusable workflow (first time using SharePoint Designer and working with workflows), and now I would like to transfer my list and the respective workflow over to another site I have created. I was able to export the workflow to a .wsp file but now I'm not sure what to do. After some research online there is a suggestion to add the "Solution" into SharePoint online, however it appears that some of my settings aren't matching those that I'm seeing in the suggestion posts, even though I have full access of the site. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jake, are you using SharePoint 2010 Workflow Engine or 2013?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013/Online (not sure if there is a difference) it's a 2013 workflow I created in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your list as a template, download the template on your PC and upload the template to the desired list gallery.

Use this article to follow the steps https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-list-templates-c3884ad1-bc49-44b8-b3d6-3bc6a01eb393

Also, I have moved SharePoint Designer workflow many times from one site to another using the below article.

https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/

Thanks

Comment: hi @Uzi, this article works for SharePoint 2010 Workflows. but are you sure it will work for 2013 Workflows?

Comment: Also, when you save a list as a template, I don't think workflow is saved with it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address my question. I also stumbled across a very similar article using the "export/import to visio" method, however please see the [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/6UP3K). It appears like I cannot export to Visio for some reason (maybe because it's a 2013 workflow?). When selecting a 2010 workflow it gives me the option to export.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov Yes the article works the same way for SharePoint 2013. I have done it many times on SP 13.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov - I have the sharepoint list moved to the site, that was pretty simple. Now I just need the workflow. I could just do it all over again in 15-20 mins but I figured there had to be a more efficient way, and it'll be a pain in the future :/

Comment: @Uzi are you using SharePoint developer when you're using the method mentioned in the article? It simply will not let me export when I try it.

Comment: @Uzi, SharePoint version and Workflow version is two different things. I used this method with SharePoint 2016 too, but it only works with Workflows 2010 engine, not with Workflows 2013. I think, Did you try it with Workflows 2013 engine?

Comment: @molodtsov You are right. We are on SP 2013 but the workflow engine we are using is still 2010. and i have not tried this with Workflow 2013 engine.

Comment: What is the functionality difference between 2010 and 2013 workflow engines besides the annoying fact that I can't export/import? Lol, I guess good to know for future instances to just use 2010 :P

Is there anyway you know of that I could convert it?

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov I just realized I forgot to tag you in my previous comment and I can't seem to edit it. Do you know if there is a way to convert a 2013 workflow to 2010?

Comment: @JakeH., I don't think conversion from 2013 to 2010 is possible. There might be a way to export-import 2013 Workflows I just never heard about a simple solution